# PHP: How do I find (Oracle) parameters in a SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, regex, parameters

Suppose you have a string: "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column1 = :var1 AND column2 = :var2"

Now, how do I get an array with all the variables like so:

```
Array
(
     [0] => :var1
     [1] => :var2
)
```

I've tried it with PHP's preg_match_all, but I struggle with the regex.

```
$varcount = preg_match_all("/ :.+ /", $sql, $out);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex instead:

```
/:\w+/
```

`\w` matches any of `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, or `_`, which is generally what parameter names consist of.

So for your code,

```
$varcount = preg_match_all("/:\\w+/", $sql, $out);
```